# Combinatorially proving $F_{n} = \sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2 \right\rfloor}\binom{n-i}{i}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers, combinatorial-proofs

Prove the following combinatorially:

$$F_{n} = \sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2 \right\rfloor}\binom{n-i}{i}$$

So, I know that the Fibonacci number counts the number of ways to cover a $1 \times n$ rectangle with checkers (covering a single square) and dominoes (covering two squares). I believe that will come up somewhere in the explanation, but I am having difficulty seeing how to show that the RHS counts the same as the Fibonacci number.

EDIT: I think I have got it figured out. If we say that the LHS is the way to cover a nx1 rectangle with checkers and dominoes, then the floor of n/2 is the max amount of dominoes you could have. In this case, i represents the number of dominoes in that particular solution, hence why you have n-i positions. Then you figure out how many unique solutions there are when you have i dominoes, adding up all the solutions with the different number of dominoes.

Comment: This is not $F_n$, it should be $F_{n+1}$. Put $n=2$ and see

Comment: Depends on what you mean by *Combinatorial proof*.  Personally, I take the (arguable) position that asserting that in Pascal's Triangle, each number is the sum of the two numbers above it is a *Combinatorial* argument.  My first try, which might not succeed, would be to attempt to use this property of Pascal's triangle to prove the assertion by induction.  I would split into two cases, depending on whether $~n~$ is odd or even.  In each case, I would use that each Fibonacci # is the sum of the two previous Fibonacci #'s, & simply explore where this leads, against the backdrop of Pascal's tri.

Comment: @SayanDutta Different people take different indexing for the Fibonacci sequence -- this question is internally consistent (correspodning to the indexing $F_0 = F_1 = 1$)

Comment: @user2661923 The proof you suggest is pure algebraic manipulation, there is no combinatorics at all in it.

Comment: @JBL I disagree.  You can construe $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}~$ as the $~a^k b^{n-k}~$ coefficient of $~(a+b)^n.~$ Then, consider the product $~(a + b)^{n+1} = (a+b)^n \times (a+b).~$  This consideration leads to the combinatoric (rather than algebraic) argument that the coefficient of $~a^{n+1}b^n~$ in the product $~(a+b)^{n+1}~$ is the sum of the $~a^nb^n~$ and $~a^{n+1}b^{n-1}~$ coefficients from $~(a + b)^n.~$  This provides a combinatoric argument that $$\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}.$$  This combinatoric argument is then the foundation of my approach.

Comment: @user2661923: Yes, Pascal's recurrence can be proved combinatorially.  No, it does not follow that a proof using induction and Pascal's recurrence is a combinatorial proof.  Obviously the term "combinatorial proof" is not sufficiently well defined for this to pass beyond being a question of opinion -- but by any reasonable definition a proof that uses only algebraic properties of the objects involved should not be called combinatorial.  (FWIW I have a PhD in combinatorics, so you don't need to explain elementary things to me.)

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$G_n = \sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2 \right\rfloor}\binom{n-i}{i}$$
so that we have
$$G_1=1,G_2=2$$
and
\begin{align*}
G_{n}+G_{n+1}&=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n-1}{1}+\binom{n-2}{2}\cdots +\binom{n+1}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n-1}{2}\cdots\\
&=\binom{n+1}{0}+\left(\binom n0+\binom{n}{1}\right)+\left(\binom{n-1}{1}+\binom{n-1}{2}\right)+\left(\binom{n-2}{2}+\binom{n-2}{3}\right)+\cdots\\
&=\binom{n+2}{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\cdots\\
&=G_{n+2}
\end{align*}
And so, $G_{n}$ is $n+1$-th Fibonacci number.

---

**Edit:** Just realized that you wanted a combinatorial proof- that one is actually easier.

Try proving that the number of $(n+1)$ length binary strings with no consecutive $1$'s relate to the Fibonacci numbers.

Now count the number of binary $(n+1)$ length strings that contain exactly $k$ $1$'s.